# Update element based on checkbox click status

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to show/hide an element based on if check-box is clicked or not.

How can I improve my code (avoiding too many "if"):

```
checkboxId= clickedcheckboxId;

if ( checkboxId== 0 ) {
    removeElements();
    $("#x1").fadeIn('fast');
}
else if ( checkboxId== 1 ) {
    removeElements();
    $("#y2").fadeIn('fast');
}
else if ( checkboxId== 2 ) {
    removeElements();
    $("#z3").fadeIn('fast');
}
else if ( checkboxId== 3 ) {
    removeElements();
    $("#w4").fadeIn('fast');
}
```

Comment: Use a switch statement.

Comment: what is different between if and switch indeed?

Comment: Switches support fallthroughs and defaults, and require fewer lines, and explicitly referring the same variable for comparison would be duplicate code

Comment: With an array you need only one if to check the range or none at all if you are sure out of range is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array:

```
if (checkboxId >= 0 && checkboxId <= 3) {
  var a = ["x1", "y2", "z3", "w4"];
  removeElements();
  $("#"+a[checkboxId]).fadeIn('fast');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement can be used to check the value of a variable and do something for each value; It's specifically designed for this purpose. See [The MDN's article on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) for more specific usage information

It's also more versatile than repeated `if` statements because it includes fallbacks and defaults

Hope that helps

EDIT:
Here's a specific example:

```
checkboxId= clickedcheckboxId;
switch(checkboxId) {
    case 0:
        removeElements();
            $("#x1").fadeIn('fast');
            break;
        case 1:
            removeElements();
            $("#y2").fadeIn('fast');
            break;
        case 2:
            removeElements();
            $("#z3").fadeIn('fast');
            break;
        case 3:
            removeElements();
            $("#w4").fadeIn('fast');
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group them

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox1" class="checkbox"/>
<div id="statment1" class="statment">
 </div>
</div>

$(".checkbox").click(function (){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
      $(this).parent().find(".statment").fadeIn(fast);
   }
   else{
      $(this).parent().find(".statment").fadeOut(fast);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='checkbox' onChange='anyFunction();'>
```

This way you will have more control on what's going on.